# redirect user to palm appcatlog by application id

Tags: webos

how to redirect user my other application in palm appcatlog. or

redirect user to particular app by application id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do by using the Application Manager service... here's an example that would run in a scene event handler:

```
this.controller.serviceRequest('palm://com.palm.applicationManager', {
    method: 'launch',
    parameters:  {
        id: 'com.palm.app.findapps',
        params: {
            scene : 'page',
            target: 'http://developer.palm.com/appredirect/?packageid=MYAPPID'
        }
    }
});
```

where MYAPPID is replaced by the application ID of the app you want to open the App Catalog to view.